# I am unable to use minus keyword in oracle 9i!

Tags: oracle9i

```
select  salary from employees order by salary desc
MINUS
select  salary from employees where rownum<10 order by salary desc;
```

I am unable to use order by with MINUS ,it says sql command not properly ended.
Please suggest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what the business question seems to be (show the salaries of employees where the salary is not in the top ten of salaries) I would think analytics would be a choice worth considering:

```
select salary 
  from (select salary,
               rank() over (order by salary) as salary_rank
          from employees
       )
 where salary_rank > 10
 order by salary;
```

Using analytics would also only scan `EMPLOYEES` once, whereas the original query would scan it twice.